# R: how to graph percentage of string items occurring in samples' lists?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file that contains many samples, and essentially 3 columns (person name, file name, and a list of ordered items).  I want to graph the occurrence of items over time, so y is all the possible labels (6 items, or 'A', 'S', 'P', 'X', 'N', 'R') and x is the percentage of times each of those labels was in that place.  So x = 1 has six data points of the number of times those items were in the first place in the list, x = 2 is the number of times items were in the second place in the list, x = 3 are occurrences in the third place, etc., for the first 5-6 items, and those items will be a line each.

Input data:

```
Participant,ImageName,GazeOrder,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Person1, fiveobjectsrandom3.jpg, A, A, S, S, P, X, N, N, R,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Person2, fiveobjectsrandom2.jpg, S, S, S, S, R, R, P, R,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Person3, fiveobjectsrandom4.jpg, N, N, S, S, R, R, R, A, P, P,
```

The rows aren't all the same length (sometimes the list ends early, sometimes it is completely blank)

When I import this in R, it will give me the first 3 columns and just name the rest X, X.1, X.2, etc, which is fine.  I know I can grab summaries with summary(imported_frame) and that table contains the counts that I want, if I knew how to get at them to graph them, but I don't know how to -- e.g.

```
 gsum <- summary(gaze_order)
       Participant                    ImageName        GazeOrder 
 Person1   :  5    fiveobjectsrandom0.jpg:47    A      :35  
 Person2   :  5    fiveobjectsrandom1.jpg:47    X      :66  
 Person3   :  5    fiveobjectsrandom2.jpg:47    N      :33  
 Person4   :  5    fiveobjectsrandom3.jpg:47    P      :25  
 Person5   :  5    fiveobjectsrandom4.jpg:47    S      :57  
 Person6   :  5                                 R      :10  
 (Other)      :205                              NA's   : 9  
  X         X.1         X.2         X.3    
  A  :28    A    :24    A    :25    A    :29  
  X  :49    X    :36    X    :25    X    :20  
  N  :44    N    :48    N    :54    N    :61  
  P  :32    P    :35    P    :40    P    :31  
  S  :57    S    :61    S    :58    S    :52  
  R  :16    R    :19    R    :19    R    :15  
 NA's: 9    NA's :12   NA's  :14  ..........
```

I can also grab the whole list of items in place 1 with imported_frame$GazeOrder, place 2 with imported_frame$X, place 3 with imported_frame$X.1, etc.

This is also [Plotting the frequency of string matches over time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167148/plotting-the-frequency-of-string-matches-over-time-in-r) basically what I need only it's more complicated than I need, and I don't know how to interpret the inner workings of that; when I started adapting it to my own data I got "Error: This function should not be called directly" when I messed with 'summarise', e.g

```
rm(list = ls())
library(tidyverse)

# read child score data
gaze_order <- read.csv(file="~/Dropbox/Eye tracking analysis/TOBII data/item_gazes_5Pictures.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings=c("", "NA"))

gaze_labels <- c("A", "X", "S", "N", "R", "P")

ggplot(data = gaze_order, mapping = aes(x = gaze_order$GazeOrder, y = gaze_labels)) +
  geom_point()

ggplot(gaze_order, summarise(Pl = sum(grepl("P", gaze_order$GazeOrder))/n(),
                            Na = sum(grepl("N", gaze_order$GazeOrder))/n(), 
                            Ba = sum(grepl("X", gaze_order$GazeOrder))/n(), 
                            So = sum(grepl("S", gaze_order$GazeOrder))/n(), 
                            Ai = sum(grepl("A", gaze_order$GazeOrder))/n(), 
                            Sp = sum(grepl("S", gaze_order$GazeOrder))/n()))
```

Desired output data is something like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdJTF.png

only instead of Jan, Feb, Mar... it's just 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...; instead of A, B, it's the possible 6 labels, 'A', 'S', 'P', 'X', 'N', 'R'.

Thoughts?  I've also been toying with grepl to count all items in all the list but it ends up being incredibly bulky and I'm sure I'm using it wrong.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Please edit your question to include (1) sample data, (2) a clear description of what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried already, and (3) your expected outcome. If unsure, see [here on how to provide a minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does that help?  The input data is as-is but I've added context regarding the summary which contains the counts I need, and a link to the graph I want something similar to.

Comment: Do you want the order of the items on the x axis or the person index on the x-axis?

Comment: and your solution below is correct, I wanted the gaze index on X and the items on y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the plot you want, there are two steps: generating the right counts and then making the actual plot. `summary` can provide counts, but it's more for interactive use and we'd prefer to have it in our table.

1. The first step is to read in the data. You can ignore the warnings here, we just don't have column names.
2. Then, we need to get our counts. Use `gather` to collect all the columns into one variable, so it's easier to plot. This is called *tidy* data. We then use two `mutate` calls to extract the actual gaze order as a number from the generated column names. We use `count` to get a count by gaze order and letter, and then use `complete` to fill in zeroes for the combinations of letter and gaze order that we didn't have because they were missing.

EDIT: to expand on `gather`. From the documentation: `gather` has parameters like this: `gather(data, key = "key", value = "value", ..., na.rm = FALSE, [some more])`. The `data` is the `tbl` passed forward through the pipe.

- The `key = "colname"` is the name of the column that is going to hold the identifier for the new rows, i.e. the column names.
- The `value = "letter"` is the name for the column that is going to hold the values for the new rows, i.e. the letters.
- The `... = -Participant, -ImageName` is the selection of columns that we want to gather up, i.e the columns whose names are gaze orders and whose values are letters. The simplest way to select them is to select *all except* `Participant` and `ImageName`. See `?dplyr::select` for more understanding of variable selection.
- `na.rm = TRUE` just drops all the missing values that we don't need.

I'd recommend looking at [this chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) for more info, and just playing around with changing the parameters to see what happens differently.

3. Finally, we can plot the right chart. We assign `gaze_order` to the `x` aesthetic and `n` to `y`, since those are the variables we want on each axis. Importantly, we can use `colour` to plot a separate line for each letter, as desired. The rest is just tweaking labels and axis breaks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_csv(
  "Participant,ImageName,GazeOrder,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Person1, fiveobjectsrandom3.jpg, A, A, S, S, P, X, N, N, R,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Person2, fiveobjectsrandom2.jpg, S, S, S, S, R, R, P, R,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Person3, fiveobjectsrandom4.jpg, N, N, S, S, R, R, R, A, P, P, "
)
#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X4' [4], 'X5' [5], 'X6' [6],
#> 'X7' [7], 'X8' [8], 'X9' [9], 'X10' [10], 'X11' [11], 'X12' [12],
#> 'X13' [13], 'X14' [14], 'X15' [15], 'X16' [16], 'X17' [17], 'X18' [18],
#> 'X19' [19], 'X20' [20], 'X21' [21], 'X22' [22], 'X23' [23], 'X24' [24],
#> 'X25' [25], 'X26' [26], 'X27' [27], 'X28' [28], 'X29' [29]
#> Warning in rbind(names(probs), probs_f): number of columns of result is not
#> a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
#> Warning: 1 parsing failure.
#> row # A tibble: 1 x 5 col     row col   expected   actual     file         expected   <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        actual 1     3 <NA>  29 columns 13 columns literal data file # A tibble: 1 x 5

tidy_tbl <- tbl %>%
  gather("colname", "letter", -Participant, -ImageName, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    colname = ifelse(colname == "GazeOrder", "X3", colname),
    gaze_order = as.integer(str_sub(colname, 2, -1)) - 2
  ) %>%
  count(gaze_order, letter) %>%
  complete(gaze_order, letter, fill = list(n = 0))

ggplot(tidy_tbl) +
  geom_line(aes(x = gaze_order, y = n, colour = letter)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Letter") +
  labs(
    x = "Gaze Order",
    y = "Count",
    title = "Count of letters by gaze order"
    )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Yeah!! I can see this is exactly what I need.  Since I'm importing from a CSV for real, this line "gather("colname", "letter", -Participant, -ImageName, na.rm = TRUE)" is parsing something specific to your way of building the CSV file versus my actual import.  Looking at the documentation for "gather", I don't understand what you're doing.  What are the "colname", "letter" doing?

Comment: added some more explanation

Comment: Does it make a difference if the entries in my CSV are actually strings?E.g. full words like Social instead of S, I just stripped text in my question so it showed up nicer.

Comment: I changed your sample input to have full words and it's totally fine.  So there must be something with the input format of a CSV file that doesn't catch here.

Comment: There are some problems in this anyway, actually.  There are -1 entries and 0 entries (I don't care if it starts at 0 or 1 incidentally) on this graph that don't make sense.  In the sample here, each of the three sample in this started at a different item (A, S, N). So the three data points should show up as (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1) and the rest (X, P, R) should be at (1, 0).  Then the next set of data points is the same, so A, S, N are all (2, 1), (2, 1), (2, 1) while the rest are (2, 0).  Then the third item for all these is all S, so that looks like (3, 3) and the rest are at (3, 0).

Comment: Fixed the issue - should have had -1 as the end of `str_sub` instead of 2. That was causing `X11` to become `-1` when I subtracted 2. Look at the edit history if it's not clear what I changed. Re: it not working on your CSV input, i would try to write it one line at a time and understand what each is doing on your input. Might need to change column formats depending on your actual data.

Comment: Okay! It was swapping GazeOrder for an X- name and the str_sub that was getting me.   When I imported from my CSV the labels were X.1, X.2, etc., so I had to change where in the string I started converting to a number and modify what column names I substituted.